# Warum benutzen wir in diesem Satz den Dativ?

Tags: grammar, dative, accusative

Ich habe eine Frage zu diesem Satz:

> Sie füttern gerade `ihren` Hund. `Unserem` haben wir vorhin schon Fressen gegeben.

In dem ersten Teil steht *ihren* im Akkusativ. Aber warum wird im zweiten Teil *unserem* im Dativ benutzt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Dativ im zweiten Teil kommt von "geben". Hier eine normalisierte Version.

> Wir (Nom.) geben unserem Hund (Dat.) Fressen (Akk.)

Answer (score 4):

*Füttern* versus *Fressen geben*:

Im ersten Satz füttern wir den Hund (der Hund ist das direkte Objekt und der Hund wird gefüttert), wohingegen im zweiten wir dem Hund Fressen geben (hier ist der Hund das indirekte Objekt und Fressen wird dem Hund gegeben).